# What is directory of com.android.internal.R?

Tags: android

R.java is not in sources/android-17/com/android/internal.
I want to see source code.

Comment: Sorry for asking stupid question.
But, I don't know why some one down voted.

Comment: I think people don't really understand your question (I don't either)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That file would be code generated as part of a firmware build. It probably does not exist in a version control system directly. It also is unlikely to hold anything of value to you -- just a bunch of integers.

That being said, you are welcome to download the source code from http://source.android.com, build it, find that specific `R.java` files, and examine its contents.